# gevent spawing - in sequence rather than concurrent

Tags: python, gevent

I am trying my hand on asynchronous programming with gevent and not able to understand the way my code works.

I am trying to ping google.com using sockets on a closed port (22) and expecting the `ping` function to happen concurrently but it is not happening

I have a python code as below

```
class Ping(object):

   def checkReachability(self,index):

      sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
      sock.settimeout(2)

      print index

      try:
           sock.connect(('google.com',22))
           gevent.sleep(0)
      except socket.error as e:
           print str(e)

      sock.close()

 def ping(self):

      threads = [gevent.spawn(self.checkReachability, i) for i in range(3)]
      gevent.joinall(threads)

if __name__ == 'main':
    m = Ping()
    m.ping()
```

I am expecting to see:

```
0
1
2
timeout
timeout
timeout
```

This is what I am getting

```
0
timed out
1
timed out
2
timed out
```

Any help would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Figured the solution.

Adding a monkey patch in import solved my issue.

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_socket()
```